# PHP Parse Error: Missing a ; in if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, parse-error

I got this error when I was running some code:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\scanner\mine.php on line 31

Line 31 is:

```
      if($_POST['thename']) {
```

I'm getting it from:

```
  echo '<h6>Settings</h6>';
  echo '<form action="" method="post">';
  echo '<b>Name:</b> <input type="text" name="thename" />';
  echo '<br /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />';
  echo '<hr><br />'
```

What's causing the parse error?

Comment: Look at the line of code above the if statement.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm an idiot. Thanks guys, I did leave out the semi-colon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is typically because the line **above** is missing an ending semi-colon.

For example:

```
echo '<hr><br />';
```

Answer (score 3):

Likely you left out a semicolon on the *previous* line, making php think that there was something more to the previous line and not expect an if statement.